# How can I get the session ID in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to get the id of the session in Laravel 4

In Laravel 3, it was a bit hacky, but possible with this code:

```
$session_id = Session::$instance->session['id'];
```

But I can't work it out in Laravel 4... referencing the `Session::$instance` object throws errors:

> Access to undeclared static property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::$instance

have tried:

```
$session_id = Session::get('id');
```

but to no avail.. any ideas?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Depends on the version of Laravel:

### Laravel 3:

```
$session_id = $_COOKIE["laravel_session"];
```

### Laravel 4.0:

*Just not versions 4.1 and above:*

```
$session_id = session_id(); //thanks Phill Sparks
```

### Laravel 4.1 (and onwards):

```
$session_id = Session::getId();
```

or

```
$session_id = session()->getId()
```

Laravel no longer uses the built-in PHP sessions directly, as a developer could choose to use various drivers to manage the sessions of visitors (docs for [Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#configuration), [Laravel 5.1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#introduction), [Laravel 5.2](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#configuration)).

Because of this, now we must use Laravel's `Session` facade or `session()` helper to get the ID of the session:

Comment: I'm picking L4 apart to find you a better solution. Don't close this yet! :-) the problem with L4 is its lack of API doc.

Comment: If you can manage to gain access to the storage driver inside `Session`, it implements the Symfony session interface - and therefore should have a `getId()` method.

Comment: This response gave me the impression that you could still use session_id() even with newer versions of Laravel 4 also.  But it turns out you actually have to use Session::getId() now instead because Laravel no longer uses standard PHP sessions.

Answer (score 48):

Just had a little hunt for myself, 
because the above answers didn't work for me (Laravel 4.1)...

Had to use this:

```
Session::getId();
```

Answer (score 5):

in laravel 5.5 first write this in your controller `use Session;`
and inside your controller function write the following line`session()->getId();`

Comment: Using the Facade is not really necessary  because you're using the global helper `session()`

Answer (score 3):

On Laravel 9:

```
$sessionId = session()->getId();
```

or

```
$sessionId = Session::getId();
```