# Prevent an already logged-in user to login in different machine

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-authorization

So I'm trying to prevent an already logged-in user to log-in in different browser or another computer. I'm thinking that I need to add an IP Address restriction, but I'm not sure how is that gonna work.

Here is my **create_users_table.php** migration file

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('name');
     $table->string('username')->unique();
     $table->string('email')->unique();
     $table->string('password');
     $table->timestamp('last_login');
     $table->boolean('isActive')->default(true);
     $table->rememberToken();
     $table->timestamps();
});
```

I'm also thinking that I need to create a restriction inside **RedirectIfAuthenticated** Middleware class.

So, here is my **RedirectIfAuthenticated.php class**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
         return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

What is the optimal solution for that, and prevent an already logged-in user from logging-in from another computer?
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to set the session value when a user logs in. Then I had a small class checking if the session ID stored is the same as the current user who is logged in.

If the user logs in from somewhere else the session ID in the DB will update and the "older" user will be logged out.

I didn't alter the Auth driver or anything, just put it on top when the user logs in. Below happens when login is successful:

```
$user->last_session = session_id();
$user->save();
```

To check if the session is valid I used below

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
      if(session_id() != Auth::user()->last_session){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('login');
      }

     return redirect('/');

    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Reference This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510220/single-session-login-in-laravel).

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering so fast. But, where I need to add the `if condition` you wrote above ???

Comment: in your middleware inside if auth check

Comment: First of all, I cannot save the session to user. `session_id` returns empty.

Comment: I accept the answer as an idea of this accomplishment. But the code isn't right.

Answer (score 5):

From Laravel 5.6 you don't need to create any database tables or such things.

in 'LoginController.php'

> app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

add this,

```
protected function authenticated()
{
    \Auth::logoutOtherDevices(request('password'));
}
```

Then from Kernel,

> app/Http/Kernel.php

in **protected $middlewareGroups** sections, remove comment from this line if already exists or just add this line -

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
```

Thats it, now if already logged-in user try to login again then previous logged-in session will be destroyed & previous logged-in user will be automatically logged out.

This should work for you.