# No simultaneous login for web using laravel

Tags: laravel-5

How to restrict same user from simultaneous login in web for same device or different device.
For eg. if a user has logged in one system and trying to login with same credentials in another device, he/she must be logged out from the previous device.

Answer (score 0):

As from Laravel 5.6, you have access to [logoutOtherDevices](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#logging-out) which does exactly what you want.

> Laravel also provides a mechanism for invalidating and "logging out" a
>   user's sessions that are active on other devices without invalidating
>   the session on their current device.

You need to make sure you have the following middleware set up in your `web` middleware group.

```
'web' => [
    // ...
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    // ...
],
```

and then, you can use it as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::logoutOtherDevices($password);
```

For earlier versions, you can take a look at this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510220/single-session-login-in-laravel).

Comment: I am using laravel 5.4

Comment: It has been asked before. Edited my answer to include a link to a SO question.