# Laravel allow one session per user

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.6, sentinel

I am trying to allow only one session per user. So if someone tries to log in when he already logged in his user account, the user is not allowed to login. The second user can login only when the first user logged out from his account.

I am using sentinel for authentication. So, I added below code in login method.

```
$user = \App\Models\User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

if (!empty($user) && isset($user->session_id) && !empty($user->session_id))
{
     return redirect()->back()->withErrors('First logout in other device')->withInput();
}
```

And I added session_id in my users table. When user login it stores session_id for that user in DB.

```
$session_id = \Session::getId();
Sentinel::update($user, ['session_id' => $session_id]);
```

And I added below code in logout function

```
Sentinel::update($user, ['session_id' => '']);
\Session::flush();
```

It is working in a flow where the first user login to one device.at the same time try to login with other devices he will not able to login in the second device. Now if he logout from first device session_id will be blank. So now he will able to login in the first device.

**Now here the problem is what if session destroys automatically or user close browser then logout method will not be called and session_id will not be blank?**. Here even though the user is not login in the first device, he will not able to login in another device.

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510220/single-session-login-in-laravel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single Session Login in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510220/single-session-login-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use a redis. Record the user who is logged in and have a timeout for it to consider when it logged in and did not do anything to leave it out.

[redis in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redis)