# how to log in from only one device

Tags: laravel

hey I'm a beginner in laravel and I am developing a website that allows the user to log in from only one device, each user can only be logged in once they can't log in from two different devices. and I'm using laravel authentication system. how to do that ? thanks a lot

Comment: this one would help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/19510428/4258328

Comment: The solution depends on what exactly your apps behaviour should be: Should the user be able to login, but automatically invalidate his previous session? Or shouldn't the user be able to login at all, until he closes the previous session?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices, you can simply add this a login:

```
Auth::logoutOtherDevices($password);
```