# how to create multiple types of token in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel and now I am facing one issue I have to log in one user at a time for web and mobile applications.
when more than one user tries to log in to a web application, automatically log out from another web application and same for mobile applications.
Please suggest a standard way to do this.

I have seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510220/single-session-login-in-laravel) but it logout from mob and web also.

Comment: use Laravel Passport https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport

Comment: @YazanFouadAldbaisy have you read my question

Answer (score 1):

This solution is working for me.

- Copy the function `sendLoginResponse` from `AuthenticatesUsers.php` in
  the framwork into your `LoginController.php` file. This overwrites the
  default `sendLoginResponse` function.
- Update your users DB (migration & db seeds etc...) to have a
  `session_id` field, type: "text".
- Extend the `sendLoginResponse` function in your `LoginController.php`
  file to achieve what you want. My function now looks like below.

  ```
   protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
   {
       $request->session()->regenerate();
       $previous_session = Auth::User()->session_id;
       if ($previous_session) {
           \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
       }

       Auth::user()->session_id = \Session::getId();
       Auth::user()->save();
       $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

       return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
           ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
   }
  ```