# How to check Laravel SessionID?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am a little confused with the session of Laravel. Laravel will start a session when client request the application and save a `_token` in the session if none of `_token` has been set.

But when using `isset($_SESSION)` to check the session, it returns false. why cannot check laravel session by `isset($_SESSION)`?

How can I get the Laravel `SessionID`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the session ID in Laravel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812747/how-can-i-get-the-session-id-in-laravel)

Comment: @Vucko thanks. I have read the answer of that question. But why we can not check laravel session by isset($_SESSION)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you get Laravel sesssion id:

```
echo Session::getId();
```

Comment: thanks. I got the session Id by Session::getId(). I also try $_cookie["laravel_session"] and it returns a value, what the value it is? is it encrypted value of Session::getId()?

Answer (score 2):

It is different depending on your Laravel version.

```
//Version 3:
$id = $_COOKIE["laravel_session"];

//Version 4:
$id = session_id();

//Laravel 4.1 and up:
$id = Session::getId();
```

Comment: Thx. mine version is 4.2.8. But when i call $id = $_COOKIE["laravel_session"], a value returns as well and the value is not the same with Session::getId().so what the value $_cookie["laravel_session"] is in version 4.2.8?