# How to send the auth cookie in the response body with Laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, cookies, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and I need to send the auth cookie on the response to the login request.

So far, I tried `Cookie::get('laravel_session')` but that would only return the cookie sent back by the client.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')))) {
    /* I need the auth token here */
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>This will do the thing: `Session::getId()`</s>

<s>Got it here: [How can I get the session ID in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812747/how-can-i-get-the-session-id-in-laravel)</s>

This actually did it well:

```
Crypt::encrypt( Session::token() )
```