# how to create session id in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

how can we create session_id in laravel 5.3 and store it into mysql database?
In PHP we use :

```
session_id();
```

for generating session_id.

but how can we create session_id in laravel 5.3?
**Thanks**

Comment: Do you want to store the actual session id of the user in your database? Or to store all sessions in your database?

Comment: i only want to add session id of the user in database thanks sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the version of Laravel:
Laravel 3:

```
$session_id = $_COOKIE["laravel_session"];
```

Laravel 4.0:

Just not versions 4.1 and above:

```
$session_id = session_id();
```

Laravel 4.1 (and onwards):

```
$session_id = Session::getId();
```

or

```
$session_id = session()->getId();
```

[Answer in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812747/how-can-i-get-the-session-id-in-laravel)